# Call to a member function paginate() on array error in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I want to create pagination in laravel but it gives error.
here is error "Call to a member function paginate() on array"

this is my query

```
$blog = DB::select("select blog_post.*,(select img_name from blog_image WHERE blog_image.bid=blog_post.bid limit 0,1) as img_name, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.bid =blog_post.bid) AS likes,
(SELECT count(*) FROM comment WHERE comment.bid =blog_post.bid ) as comments ,
(SELECT count(*) FROM blog_share WHERE blog_share.bid =blog_post.bid ) as  share 
from blog_post WHERE status=1 AND is_draft=0 AND is_publish=1 AND is_delete=0")->paginate(2);
```

Comment: Write your query using Eloquent. You can't use `paginate` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks but I need All result in only one query as I write query above. This is possible in laravel. If yes then how?

Comment: Yes it's possible in Laravel, using a combination of the eloquent functions and `DB::raw()`.

Comment: Can you give me example for this

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to rewrite your query using [Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent). For example:

```
$blog = DB::table('blog_post')->where([ 'status' => 1, 'is_draft' => 0, 'is_publish' => 1, 'is_delete' = 0 ])->paginate(2);
```

You don't strictly need to put all the counts / inner-queries into one query. You can use Eloquent Relationships and Mutators to get that information for you. For example, the following Relationship to get the image:

```
class BlogPost extends Model
{

  public function image()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('BlogImage');
  }

}
```